# Starting multiple independent processes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to start multiple processes at the same time using a for loop. I want each to be created in it's own console window. So far i have the following:

```
for i in {1..5}; do konsole -e "./program arg1 arg2"; done
```

However , this simply runs them one after another, where i want them to run concurrently. I've tried using '&' but i can't get i to play nicely with the loop.

Comment: Replace the `;` before `done` with `&`. But first check whether `konsole -e "./program arg1 arg2"` does what you think it does.

Comment: @AlexP You should write that up as an answer. I would have upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A background task is started by putting a `&` at the end of the command.  Your loop would start `konsole` in the background if you wrote it as

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    konsole -e "./program arg1 arg2" &
done
```

or, on a single line,

```
for i in {1..5}; do konsole -e "./program arg1 arg2" & done
```

The `&` is a command terminator, just like `;` (and newline and a few others), so it *replaces* the `;` that you originally had there.

Would you want the script to wait for the started background tasks to finish, add a `wait` at the end:

```
for i in {1..5}; do konsole -e "./program arg1 arg2" & done; wait
```